# Showing the Initiation Form "automatically"

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, initiation-form

Environment is Sharepoint online (Office 365)

Trying to have a workflow run on a Sharepoint list, so that somebody adds a list item with a title, and then they are automatically shown the initiation form.

If I create the list item and then manually start the workflow, the initiation form is shown, but if the workflow is set to start automatically, the initiation form is not shown.

The reason for using the initiation form is that I do not see a method to include data from the new list item in the workflow for populating the content of emails sent by the workflow.

I appreciate that I may well be attacking the problem the wrong way round, I'm very much a newbie when it comes to Sharepoint.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that what I was trying to do was impossible, but found a way to populate a variable in the workflow from the list

[SharePoint 2010 approval workflows: how to pull data from against a different list](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/43875)